# Replacing double space with single space within an array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, replace

I need to replace every double space with a single space in a char array given to me, and then every time I replace the double space with a single, I must add "X" to the end of the array.

I really have no idea where to start with this.

Comment: Can you please post what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
   String orig = "Hello  World";
   String next = orig.replace ("  ", " ");
   while (next.length() != orig.length ()) {
      next = next + "X":
   }
```

A char array can easily be converted to a String [eh](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[])).

Comment: When constantly concatenating to a string, it is much better to use StringBuilder since it prevents memory wastage. Every addition of character to a string results in the creation of a new string.

Comment: @DebosmitRay Yes, generally speaking I agree with what you say, but in such a little case such as this, I doubt that you will find any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Extending @ScaryWombat's answer to print an X for each space that was removed:

```
String orig = new String(myCharArray);
String next = orig.replace ("  ", " ");
for(int i = 0; i < (orig.length() - next.length()); i++) {
    next = next + "X":
}
myCharArray = next.toCharArray();
```

Comment: When constantly concatenating to a string, it is much better to use StringBuilder since it prevents memory wastage. Every addition of character to a string results in the creation of a new string.

Comment: plus 1 - as I missed the `for each` part

Comment: With these, the array isn't being used, so how are the unknown strings of the char [] myArray being changed?

Comment: Edited to use a char[] called `myCharArray`.